# SQl,UPDATE INNER JOIN You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, sql-update

```
UPDATE A set A.amount = A.amount 
FROM product_in_stock AS A 
INNER JOIN move_str_start AS B ON A.id_model = B.id_model 
WHERE B.id_move=121 AND A.id_stock=7;
```

I have error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'FROM product_in_stock AS A INNER JOIN move_str_start AS B ON
> A.id_model = B.id_m' at line 1

Comment: This is the Sql server way to write it. The MySql syntax for this is not standard.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: neither syntax is standard. The SQL standard does not define any join possibilities in the UPDATE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update product_in_stock AS A 
INNER JOIN move_str_start AS B ON A.id_model = B.id_model 
SET A.amount=A.amount+B.count  
WHERE B.id_move=121 AND A.id_stock=7;
```

PS This is Answer

Comment: Is this the answer ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha
Yes